# In OpenOffice.org Writer, how do I print page numbers?

Tags: openoffice

I would like to print a document with page numbers at the bottom. What is the easiest way to do this in OpenOffice.org Writer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [OpenOffice Wiki](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Writer_Guide/Page_numbering):

> #### Inserting a header
>
> In OOo, headers are specified by page styles.
>
> 1. Open the Page Style dialog box for the desired page style (right-click > **Modify**).
> 2. Select the **Header** tab.
> 3. Under Header, check **Header on** and click **OK**.
>
> #### Simple page numbering
>
> The simplest case is to have the page number at the top of every page and nothing more. To do this, put the cursor on the header and select:
>
> Insert > Fields > Page Number.
>
> #### More complex variations
>
> There are a lot of interesting variations that you can apply without further knowledge of page styles. Here are some suggestions:
>
> - Right-align the header to make the page number appear on the top-right:
> - Place the cursor in the header.
> - Click the **Align Right** icon (or right-click anywhere in the header and select **Alignment > Right**).
> - Add (type) the word **page** so the header reads **page 1, page 2**, and so on. This also requires using the *Page Number* field.
> - Add the document title so the header reads, for example: **Joe's favourite poems**, left justified, and **page x** with right justification, where x is the value of the *Page Number* field. Consider using a tab to separate the title from the page number.
> - OOo also has a *Page Count* field (**Insert > Fields > Page Count**). Using it, you could, for example, have a header that reads **page 2 of 12**.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=61130) thread.

It basically says that you have to activate the footer or header (in the page style properties) to tell OpenOffice where it has to put the page number.

I can't verify this at the moment as I am at work, however it's worth a try!